# How to set starting value for an Identity primary key in Entity Framework code first?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6, code-first

In my project I am creating the `Appointments` table using Entity Framework code first. When I set my integer primary key, `AppointmentNo` as `[Key]` and `[Required]`, it creates the table with initial primary key starting with 1.

I want the appointment numbers to start at 1000. My database is SQL Server. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

```
[DataContract]
public class Appointment
{
    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int AppointmentNo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public string DoctorUN { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    public string PatientUN { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974554/ef-code-first-how-to-set-identity-seed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible using ef annotations,but you can execute sql in migration UP method

```
Sql("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Appointment', RESEED, 1000)");
```

Comment: I  created the table from the SQL Server  Management Studio and used your query there before I executed my code, that got the job done. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In entity framework you can do this:

```
builder.Entity<EntityName>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("TabelName");
            b.Property(x => x.ColumnName).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().UseIdentityColumn(1000,1);
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

EF Core 3.1
You can open your migration script and edit it before updating database.
EF creates this line for the identity column:
.Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),

you can update it to anything you want:

.Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "Your Starting Value, Your Increment Value"),

Example: If I want OrderId column on tblOrder to start from 1000 and increment by 1:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "tblOrder",
    schema: "dbo",
    columns: table => new
    {
        OrderID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1000, 1"),        
        CDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "getdate()")
    },
.
.
.
```

Answer (score -2):

As long as the type of the primary key property is numeric or GUID, Code First will, by convention, automatically configure the key as an identity column.

from:[EF and identity columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946212/how-to-mark-identity-column-properly-with-entity-framework-6-1)

Comment: But is there a way to set the starting value to a specific value and increment from that point onward ?

Comment: not clear from the docs.  easy to fix afterwards though.  and a good argument against code first. (flame on!)

Comment: read the question carefully before answering