# How to Change Asp.net Core Identity AspNetUsers Role Primary key Data Type

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

I am trying to change the Data Type of .NET core Identity AspNetUsers primary key data type from GUID to Int. but couldn't find a way.  What can I do to change only AspNetUsers primary key data type.

Comment: You should just inherit from `IdentityUser<int>`, `IdentityRole<int>` and `IdentityDbContext<MyUser, MyRole, int>`?

Comment: Also why would you want your users and roles to have an `int` id? Anyone can guess them so easily. `0` will probably be User, and `1` will probably be Administrator...

Comment: I just want RoleId as Int but UserId as it is

Comment: With Identity that's not possible

Comment: Can you tell how to set starting value of primary key of a table as 100 an increment by 1 for PostgreSql using EF Core?

Comment: I think you can only do so using the [fluent api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72218778/8941307) (in your `DbContext.Configure`). Kinda similar to what @Laxmikant wrote

Comment: I exectly did the same thing by it is starting from 1

Comment: `modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>(b =>
            {
                b.ToTable("Employee");
                b.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd().UseIdentityColumn(1000, 1);
            });`

Comment: Did you perform `dotnet ef migrations add xxx` and `dotnet ef database update` after making some changes?

Comment: i used add-migration "xxx" and update-database after changes

Comment: May be it works for SqlServer

Answer (score 0):

on model creating event

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
{

   // Primary key
    b.HasKey(u => u.Id).HasColumnType("int");
    
    //other configuration
            
});
```

then run in package manager console

```
Run Update-Database
```

Comment: keybuilder does not contain a definition for HasColumnType asp.net core... Giving this error

Comment: check this - https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hascolumntype-method